# Wordpress homepage stamped with a custom category body class, - why?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm running a function to insert custom body class which works on categories, pages and posts, but on the front page ( which has no categories ) it **still stamps** the page with a body class of the last post's category value.

I'm thinking that somehow the category value is not being properly reset? How do I do that?

Thanks.

```
function dynamicbody() {
$category = get_the_category();
if ( $category[0]->category_nicename == cat1 ) {
    add_filter('body_class','my_class_names');
    function my_class_names($classes) { $classes[] = 'cat1'; return $classes; }
} else if ( $category[0]->category_nicename  == cat2 ) {
    add_filter('body_class','my_class_names');
    function my_class_names($classes) { $classes[] = 'cat2'; return $classes; }
} else if ( is_home() ) {
    add_filter('body_class','my_class_names');
    function my_class_names($classes) { $classes[] = 'home'; return $classes; }
}
}

add_action('wp_head', 'dynamicbody');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using the `is_home` code, you would be better off using `is_front_page`, so change the following line

```
else if ( is_home() ) {
    add_filter('body_class','my_class_names');
    function my_class_names($classes) { $classes[] = 'home'; return $classes; }
}
```

to this

```
else if ( is_front_page() ) {
    add_filter('body_class','my_class_names');
    function my_class_names($classes) { $classes[] = 'home'; return $classes; }
}
```

If you are still experiencing issues after this, I would change the whole code to this

```
function dynamicbody() {
 $category = get_the_category();
 if ( $category[0]->category_nicename == cat1 && !is_front_page()) {
    add_filter('body_class','my_class_names');
    function my_class_names($classes) { $classes[] = 'cat1'; return $classes; }
 } else if ( $category[0]->category_nicename  == cat2 && !is_front_page()) {
    add_filter('body_class','my_class_names');
    function my_class_names($classes) { $classes[] = 'cat2'; return $classes; }
 } else if ( is_front_page()) {
    add_filter('body_class','my_class_names');
    function my_class_names($classes) { $classes[] = 'home'; return $classes; }
 }
}

add_action('wp_head', 'dynamicbody');
```

Comment: Yes, it works! This was my first post on StackOverflow, - thanks for your help, I hope I can pass this good deed onwards and help someone else on these forums sometime! :) Good day, sir.

Comment: Your very welcome. Glad I could help! Stack Overflow users have saved my ass a few times as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, just check first whether a category exists or not

```
function dynamicbody() {
$category = get_the_category();
if($category)
{
if ( $category[0]->category_nicename == cat1 ) {
    add_filter('body_class','my_class_names');
    function my_class_names($classes) { $classes[] = 'cat1'; return $classes; }
} else if ( $category[0]->category_nicename  == cat2 ) {
    add_filter('body_class','my_class_names');
    function my_class_names($classes) { $classes[] = 'cat2'; return $classes; }
} else if ( is_home() ) {
    add_filter('body_class','my_class_names');
    function my_class_names($classes) { $classes[] = 'home'; return $classes; }
}
}
}

add_action('wp_head', 'dynamicbody');
```